# inline-block div moves down when jquery html() is called on it

Tags: jquery, css, html

please have a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NtxG9/1/

I have two divs, with the same class, and they are displayed as inline-block.
If I call `$('#parent1').html('some text');` then it moves down.

Would someone explain why this happens?

thanks!

**EDIT**

thanks for all these solutions, but I am still unclear as to why this happens.
Why does changing a div's contents affect it's position?

Comment: @Adrift, you posted an answer, but now it has disappeared. I wonder why, because it was a good explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Explanation:**

You can used to display inline-block that means by default `inline-block` is `baseline` than define to always `vertical-align top` if you define `display:inline-block` element in any html element.

Try using

```
.parent {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NtxG9/3/)

Comment: ok, I'll accept your answer, although I don't fully understand the explantion. But I see I have to read up on this baseline property. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use `vertical-align: top;` to align everything to the top.

And for older IE versions you might have to trigger hasLayout:

```
/* For IE 7 */
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```

Answer (score 0):

see here
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/animesh/NtxG9/4/)

add this css

```
float:left;
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding float:left property to parent class. It looks as a floating issue. I added this property and it worked fine.